# VPN works in VM guest, but not VM host

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a switch, the switch has 3 connected cables.

The NAS
The PC
The Internet

My VPN is with SonicWall and I use NetExtender. The Bottom line is, I use exactly the same programs to connect with the same credentials. Both report that they are connected and tunneling traffic through the IPs.

A important thing here I feel is that, when connected to the VPN I am unable to connect to my NAS and if I am already connected, that connection is blocked and no longer works. I am connected to my NAS via a "LinkOnly" connection. Nothing else will/would work.

However on the guest I can access pages that are behind our VPN. But on the host I cannot. The guest has a NAT connected network adaptor with VmWare Workstation v16.

I asked IT to check the logs on the failed requests and it came back with:
`some 403s just after I asked you to hit turo-green with an x-forwarded-for header value of 2a01:4b00:86f0:e00:6c71:9e79:XXX:9597, 64.252.XX.126. The 1st IP is hyperoptic (I guess thats the ISP for you apartment or block of apartments), the 2nd is AWS cloudfront`

When digging a little bit `curl ifconfig.co` gives `2a01:4b00:86f0:e00:6c71:9e79:e8d:9597`  but should be giving `195.114.XXX.217`

```
Before connection 

(base) hutber@hutber:~$ ip route 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.168.22 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.59.152 metric 101 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
172.16.64.0/24 dev vmnet8 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.64.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 600 
192.168.246.0/24 dev vmnet1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.246.1 
224.0.0.0/4 dev enp2s0 proto static scope link metric 100 
224.0.0.0/4 dev enp8s0 proto static scope link metric 101 

After connecting    

(base) hutber@hutber:~$ ip route
default via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 via 10.x.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.168.22 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.59.152 metric 101 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
172.16.64.0/24 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
172.16.64.0/24 dev vmnet8 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.64.1 
192.0.2.1 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
192.0.2.1 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.57.3 
192.168.1.0/24 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 600 
192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 scope link 
192.168.246.0/24 via 10.10.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
192.168.246.0/24 dev vmnet1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.246.1 
195.114.XX.217 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 
224.0.0.0/4 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
224.0.0.0/4 dev enp2s0 proto static scope link metric 100 
224.0.0.0/4 dev enp8s0 proto static scope link metric 101
```

You might be thinking, why doesn't he just ask IT. Well IT won't support linux and I get headaches from using OSX through sheer frustration (sorry)

```
hutber@hutber:~$ curl --interface ppp0 ifconfig.co
195.114.103.217
```

I have no firewalls on my host machine that I am aware of.

**[Edit]**

So I believe I need to create a ip route to map this IP     `195.114.XX.217 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1` away from `192.168.1.1` however my VPN that is unable to connect is `169.254.168.22` so I imagine its because the VPN is tunneling all traffic?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing is clear. Ping, traceroute from vm and host, compare results. Check DNS.

Comment: Thanks @gapsf sorry to ask, which ip should I be Ping'ing, traceroute, the url that is not accessible from the main pc? I am also unsure how to check DNS. I will try some things and see where I can get if you don't get back to me yet.

Comment: It looks like your problem is the route `192.168.1.0/24 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link `, since that overrides the route to your local network. You should be able to test that by deleting the route. Does that impact the problem?

Comment: Thanks @larsks to delete just this route I assume its `ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.xx.57.3`? I just don't want to go deleting or editing my routes without first knowing its the correct command :)

Comment: That's the correct command, yes. Route changes aren't persistent, so you shouldn't be nervous about editing them. If something breaks, just reboot.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, if I remove those routes, there were 3x xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 via 10.xx.57.3 that I removed. So with those removed, I am able to access my NAS. But of course still not able to access the VPN sections that I need to access

Comment: "But of course still not able to access the VPN sections that I need to access" what does  it means exactly? What ip address you want to reach from the host? I cant get between what points your vpn is established? What is 192.168.1.1 device and how it configured?

Comment: It means that when I remove all of the 192.168.1.0 or similar IPs from my IP routes I can access the nas drive again, whilst still connected to the VPN. I was doing as suggested by @larsks. I am sorry I am unable to help more concisely though. The IP address I would like to have access to, whilst still accessing my NAS is `195.114.XX.217`. I believe `192.168.1.1` is my internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having read the comments under question, I think @larsks has this sorted.

Ok let me have a try at expanding on it:

From the first routing table:

1. You have a wireless (wlo1) and two ethernet (enp2s0, enp8s0) interfaces.
2. For reasons unknown to me, you have a multicast address, some streaming software perhaps (pure speculation).
3. For reasons unknown to me, you have link-local IPv4 addresses (subnet 169.254.0.0/16). You have both of them connected to some devices, your interfaces have IP addresses 169.254.168.22 (enp2s0) and 169.254.59.152 (enp8s0). I speculate some software like avahi mDNS.
   `Note`: I have only seen these on Windows DHCP configured connections between computers without a DHCP server running (e.g. just a switch or a direct link), it can be thought of as an automatic fallback IP address.
4. You connect to your router (a.k.a. wireless home modem) via Wi-Fi (wlo1). Your IP address is 192.168.1.104 and its (the gateway) IP address is 192.168.1.1 within subnet 192.168.1.0/24. `Note`: When in doubt, assume a router operates (as the gateway) with at least one of these addresses: 192.168.0.1/24, 192.168.1.1/24, 192.168.100.1/24 in CIDR notation. I have encountered some home routers which redirect to the correct subnet by occupying both subnets.
5. You have two running virtual machines with different virtual networks (192.168.246.0/24, 172.16.64.0/24). They are NAT networks with your machine (hypervisor) being the gateway in those networks. Hypervisor respectively has IPs 192.168.246.1 and 172.16.64.1.

Building upon previous observation, from second routing table:

1. For some reason, you now know Wi-Fi is the interface to access your NAS (195.114.XX.217). I suspect you just had not connected up until previous output, nothing special about the VPN.
2. Your supposedly mDNS client (responsible for 169.254.0.0/16) tried its luck with ppp0 just as it did with wlo1 previously. Nothing special again.
3. Your VPN (ppp0) has added routes for 10.0.0.0/8, 128.0.0.0/1, 192.0.2.1/24. **192.168.1.0/24** (all through your VPN IP address 10.XX.57.3). `Note`: Your VPN address is usable as long as you have internet connection to connect to the VPN server. So all these networks are dependent on your home network being functional. That bold subnet is trouble, more on that later.
4. Your virtual networks are being advertised through your VPN IP address (10.XX.57.3), it is probably due to how NAT works. A packet arriving from the *other side* (any of afore-mentioned subnets) would this way be routed back to the appropriate virtual machine; almost certainly having a connection initiated by the VM first.

Having parsed all that, these are where the problem lies:

```
default via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600
```

```
192.168.1.0/24 via 10.xx.57.3 dev ppp0 scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 600
```

Your computer can't connect to the home router (192.168.1.1) because it tries it over the ppp0 interface whose router is inaccessible somehow, at least from the machine's point of view.

I suspect the ppp0 interface would not loop packages around forever and just drop them after the first looping occurs, rather that trying the next interface in line (wlo1) for performance reasons. Pure speculation again.

Yet, if you had higher priority (lower integer) for wlo1 than ppp0 you would have your home LAN connection preserved, and thus NAS and VPN connectivity. But mind that 192.168.1.0/24 over the VPN would not work, as it would be shadowed by your home LAN.

**I propose you change your home LAN subnet under Wi-Fi configuration of your router device to some subnet which haven't been written above. I suggest something conforming to the form 192.168.XXX.1/24.**

P.S. I speculate again but I think you were able to connect to the NAS after editing routing table post VPN connection, because you already had this line there:

```
195.114.XX.217 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1
```

So when you sought 195.114.XX.217, table entry meant it should have gone through 192.168.1.1. Having IP address 192.168.1.104/24 on wlo1, it was a LAN connection to 192.168.1.1 and packet could be sent without a gateway, and it did. If you tried any other address, you would not know to send it over 192.168.1.1 (the gateway) and fail, so no internet but NAS connection. That's my best guess.

If this satisfies as an answer go upvote @larsks 's comment too. He was the lighthouse.